# Using System.Net.Socket, how can we know when the remote socket is closed?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Ok so here is how things are going:

```
[Server] Start
[Server] Socket.AcceptConnection
[Client] Start
[Client] Socket.Connect 
[Server] Receive //blocking
[Client] Send
[Server] Print
[Server] Receive
[Client] Close socket
```

Is there any way to know when the client as closed the connection?
I am currently using the fake packet trick as described on MSDN where on a separate thread I do a

```
[Server] socket.Send(byte[], 0,0);
```

And I check if it throw any error but it does not, even if the client as closed the socket.

P.S. I am actualy thinking, might it be a problem if I have a socket on the server side (TCP) and a TcpClient on the client side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs for [Socket.Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connected.aspx):

> The value of the Connected property
>   reflects the state of the connection
>   as of the most recent operation. If
>   you need to determine the current
>   state of the connection, make a
>   nonblocking, zero-byte Send call. If
>   the call returns successfully or
>   throws a WAEWOULDBLOCK error code
>   (10035), then the socket is still
>   connected; otherwise, the socket is no
>   longer connected.

Note that your current call is a blocking call as far as I can see - you need to make a nonblocking call according to that documentation.

Comment: If you get a FIN, then the last receive (callback or blocking) should be 0 length. If you get that, then test the socket state.

Answer (score 1):

TCP connection should return `0`, i.e. `EOF`, on a read from socket on which FIN has been received, but you'd be much better off designing your protocol so parties tell each other when it's time to disconnect/close the socket. Also playing with the same socket from multiple threads will bite you - avoid it.

Comment: What should happen when the client connection is interrupted? (i.e. No gracefull fail option :(, the server will be stuck on receive no?)

Comment: I don't know .NET socket API, but would imagine you'd get an exception. Native C API returns -1 and specific error depends on what exactly happened - RST was received, timeout elapsed, etc.

Comment: Nah, that's what I thought but when I try to send with my other thread on a closed socket, it returns 0, no exception, everything seems fine.

Comment: Well, Send() returns number of bytes sent, you give it zero, it sends zero :) Check the documentation on what Receive() should return on FIN-ed socket - I bet it's -1 or zero, i.e. a special value.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
if (part1 & part2)
{//connection is closed
}
```